# file not found when running executable written in Go

Tags: ubuntu, go, alpine-linux

If I build https://github.com/m3europe/procwrap on go 1.7.1 on alpine and try to run the binary on ubuntu trusty I get file not found, and the same if I build on trusty and try to run on alpine.  I suspect this is to do with linking somehow but I'm a little out of my depth here having spent most of my career so far in managed execution environments.  My seemingly naive understanding is that an AMD64 build should work on any AMD64 linux distro, no?

The below Dockerfile demonstrates the issue.  The executable downloaded at line 6 was built on golang:1.7.1-alpine image:

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN mkdir /procwrap
WORKDIR /procwrap
RUN wget https://github.com/myles-mcdonnell/procwrap/releases/download/v1.0.0/procwrap.v1.amd64 -O procwrap
RUN wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/myles-mcdonnell/procwrap/master/procwrap.toml -O procwrap.toml
RUN chmod +x procwrap
CMD ./procwrap -v
```

Comment: I don't get it. Is the problem that you can't build it or that the resulting binary throws an error?

Comment: What file is not found? Can you show exactly what you're doing, and the exact error you receive?

Comment: please see update, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `ldd you-bin-path` to print shared library dependencies, maybe the two system have different lib path structure.

Comment: I second this: Alpine is known for using uLibc or musl (can't recall correctly ATM) as its system-wide standard C library while Ubuntu uses plain GNU libc for this purpose.  Under certain circumstances (namely, working with DNS on Linux), Go would build a *dynamic* executable depending on the system's C standard library. In your case these libraries will be different across platform.

Comment: A way to go would be to re-building your program with `go install -a -tags netgo ...` which would ensure a (simpler) plain Go implementation of the DNS resolver will be used. I think you'll need a relatively up-to-date Go for this (works for me with 1.7).